# Model suggestion for zero-bounded dependent variable

Tags: mixed-model, anova

I have a repeated measures dataset (8 measurements) with three experimental groups (Randomly generated). The dependent variable (Y) is on a continuous scale bounded inferiorly at 0. I am trying to model the effect of the different groups and time on Y. What would be the appropriate model here? -

- repeated ANOVA is compromised by the non-normal distribution of Y
  (see histogram -  I tried adding a minuscule amount and logging, but
  still really to no help)
- Mixed linear models are not bounded inferiorly at 0. Perhaps one of the more advanced non-linear mixed models?
- Area under the curves for all timepoints stratified by group?
- Bayesian approaches?

Raw Y   [image: Absolute values]

Logged Y[image: Logged values]

Histogram of logged Y
[image]

Comment: What was a "minuscule amount"? log of (y + 1e-9) is for example usually a much worse idea than log of (y + 1).  More importantly, is zero itself an observed value?

Comment: Y is indeed an observed value—as time increases, the proportion of actual 0-values increases. Minuscule amount: arbitrarily chosen —.0001

Comment: I guess you need to say much more about the underlying science. It sounds as if you have a set-up in which the amount is something is decreasing and in particular it may vanish (or at least become undetectable). If so, you need a model geared to that, although I am not clear what it would be.

Comment: It is a measurement of a quantity that can vanish — I did fit a Bayesian beta-regression where the posterior predictive check looks reasonable for all measurements - but should the pp-check also be repeated for each time-point?

Comment: Sorry, can't help at all on Bayesian detail.

Comment: I would use a longitudinal semiparametric model (e.g., proportional odds model) on the raw data, either the Bayesian or frequentist version.  More at https://fharrell.com/post/rpo .  Such models are invariant to Y transformations and generalize the Wilcoxon/Mann-Whitney/Kruskal-Wallis tests.

Comment: Seems like a generalized linear mixed model with error distribution given by some nonnegative random variable (e.g. Gamma) would do the trick?

Comment: Will you explain the histogram? Why does it have both vertical lines and vertical bars? Why doesn’t it have color like the other graphs? And why would you reject normal approximations to the graphs in the panels of the histogram?

Comment: As time passes, the zero values increase in frequency, but there are still measurements >0. I agree that these measurements above 0 look gaussian, but the spike at 0 is troublesome.

Comment: This looks like it can be modelled with some sort of zero inflated model, but which model would be suitable depends on the underlying physics. What sort of data are we looking at? If you have discrete values then you could use a zero inflated Poisson model.

Comment: Anyway, your graphs show a distribution with multiple peaks and you need to explain why this is and what aspect in these you want to model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given any thought to the three parameter Weibull distribution?  Which would be SEV with log(x). Also known as Complimentary log-log ,or Gompit on log(x) With a threshold.  Another idea is to treat time zero issues like time zero failures like warranty claims for vehicles that have not been sold. Basically the cumulative percentage has a non zero intercept. You analyze the non zero values separately, then add the percentage of the zero values to them.

Though I am not clear on the actual response, I suspect the "0" values are actually Left Censored values. Left Censoring: we only know the events happened sometime prior (eg prior to Y=1 (log_vol=0), but do not know when. Looking at the histograms of "log_vol" there are no values less than log_vol=0 (which is Y=1) except for the log(0.0001) spike. I suspect the spike is an artifact of this left censoring @ ~ Y=1. The time variable, appears to be shifting the distribution snapshots leftward toward 1 (log_vol=0), resulting in higher counts of values less than 1 (log_vol=0) as I try to show in the figure below using Logistic Link to illustrate on log_vol. The histagrams appear to be left skewed, so a SEV (aka Gumbull, Gompertz, Complimentary log-log) link may fit better. This becomes Weibull (SEV of log(x) is ~ Weibull) with Weibull slope ß = l/scale. With SEV scale= 1 is actually the exponential distribution (Poisson counts, Exponential time between events). If so, I suggest that a Survival analysis might be what you may want. Here is a link with an answer you may find helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968606/left-censoring-for-survival-data-in-r
[image: Left Censor with Logit]

[image: Left Censor SEV]

Answer (score 0):

So I did fit a longitudinal bayesian proportional odds model using brlm as suggested by Frank Harrells. The fit is quite good and seems to model what I wanted while still retaining the inferior bounds. However, I would have liked to do a posterior predictive check, but I don't quite comprehend the calculation of the predicted probabilities given all these confusing intercepts and the other "standard" Bayesian toolboxes don't seem to recognize the brlm models. Moreover, I tried calculating the contrast between the different groups at t=2, but I am at odds as how I can convert the value into the raw Y-units. The calculated contrast between the green and red group at t=2 is 1.866.

[image]